# QLocale codeToTerritory only worls with 2-digit codes

Tags: c++, qt, qlocale

I would like to get the Country name for any ISO 3166 country codes. My project currently uses 3-digit codes, so if possible, from that. According to the Qt documentation QLocale::countryToTerritory should solve this, but in my test programs, it only works with 2-digit codes. I also tried the deprecated codeToCountry function, but it has the same result. Also the numeric code does not have any result.

Here is a simple test program:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <QLocale>
#include <QDebug>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString l2 = "DE";
    QString l3 = "DEU";
    QString d3 = "276";

    qDebug() << QLocale::codeToCountry(l2) << QLocale::codeToCountry(l3) << QLocale::codeToCountry(d3);
    qDebug() << QLocale::codeToTerritory(l2) << QLocale::codeToTerritory(l3) << QLocale::codeToTerritory(d3);

    return a.exec();
}
```

The output is:

```
QLocale::Germany QLocale::AnyTerritory QLocale::AnyTerritory
QLocale::Germany QLocale::AnyTerritory QLocale::AnyTerritory
```

I tried with a few different countries, all with the same results.

I built the project with Qt 6.3.0 with MSVC2019 compiler on windows.

Is the documentation simply wrong, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code source of [codeToTerritory](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/text/qlocale.cpp#n183) you can see that the country code is compared against a list of codes contained in *territory_code_list*. This variable is defined in [qlocale_data_p.h](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/text/qlocale_data_p.h#n5914).

It seems that only the ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 code (i.e. 2-character code) is used in this list. There is neither "DEU" nor "276" in *territory_code_list*, which means that QLocale::AnyTerritory is returned.

So I do not know if the documentation is wrong, but at least it is imprecise.

EDIT: digging a bit further, the list of codes is generated from https://unicode.org/Public/cldr/. These files only contain 2-letter codes for countries (there are some 3-digit codes corresponding to continents, but none for countries).

EDIT2: so, you need to write the conversion from 3-digits / 3-letters code to alpha2-code to be able to use Qt methods. You can get data from [this website](https://www.iban.com/country-codes).

Comment: It seems like I also misread it a little. The exact wording in the documentation is: ' two-letter or three-digit territoryCode', so it does not say 3-letter code. As such, the documentation is not exactly incorrect, but a little misleading maybe. I was hoping for a solution where I don't have to store the code-country name pairs myself, but it seems like I can't do it like that.